# Regex any uppercase variants of specific string

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to catch if a specific string `thefolder` contains any uppercase characters.

```
http://www.example.com/thefolder = false
http://www.example.com/theDirectory = false
http://www.example.com/theFolder = true
http://www.example.com/ThefolDeR = true
http://www.example.com/THEFOLDER = true
```

So far I have the below regex but it will also return true for `theDirectory`, which is not desired.

```
(?=.*[A-Z]).+
```

Its important to note it must exclusively match the specific string `thefolder` as this is for an IIS rewrite which must not effect the rest of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just doing an IIS rewrite, you can just match `thefolder` and check the **Ignore Case** check box, then do whatever you need to do.

Try something like this in your rewrite config file:

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="thefolder" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
</rule>
```

**Update:**

It's a bit convoluted, but this regex should do it.

```
.*(?=.*[A-Z])([tT][hH][eE][fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]).*
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more descriptive. I tried that but the problem stems from AngularJS requiring a hardcoded `<base href="/thefolder/">` . This means I have to use a rewrite/redirect to catch the user who enters an uppercase.

Comment: Cheers, but Angular is client side so it will not detect the rewrite. I've been playing with `<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />` but it just goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: @remarsh Alright, this update should do it. Hopefully... If lookaheads are supported.

Answer (score 2):

This might work. Uses a lookahead to see if `thefolder` (length 9) has a
capital letter. If so, it matches.

`(?=(?i:thefolder))(?![a-z]{9})(.{9})`

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?=
      (?i: thefolder )
 )
 (?! [a-z]{9} )
 ( .{9} )
```

In the worst case, there is always permutations (No syntax but class and alternation).
But, this will always result in a large string.

`T[hH][eE][fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]|[tT]H[eE][fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]|[tT][hH]E[fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]|[tT][hH][eE]F[oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]|[tT][hH][eE][fF]O[lL][dD][eE][rR]|[tT][hH][eE][fF][oO]L[dD][eE][rR]|[tT][hH][eE][fF][oO][lL]D[eE][rR]|[tT][hH][eE][fF][oO][lL][dD]E[rR]|[tT][hH][eE][fF][oO][lL][dD][eE]R`

```
   T [hH] [eE] [fF] [oO] [lL] [dD] [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] H [eE] [fF] [oO] [lL] [dD] [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] E [fF] [oO] [lL] [dD] [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] [eE] F [oO] [lL] [dD] [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] [eE] [fF] O [lL] [dD] [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] [eE] [fF] [oO] L [dD] [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] [eE] [fF] [oO] [lL] D [eE] [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] [eE] [fF] [oO] [lL] [dD] E [rR] 
|  [tT] [hH] [eE] [fF] [oO] [lL] [dD] [eE] R
```

Comment: Urgh! IIS doesnt support that sort of regex. Error: "Syntax incorrect"

Comment: Ok, I'll delete the post. Better check what engine it uses and if lookahead assertions are supported.

Answer (score -1):

I think this regex is what you are looking for:

```
^[^A-Z]+$
```

[**Here**](https://regex101.com/r/oF0cS2/2) is the example.

This returns:

```
http://www.example.com/thefolder    = true
http://www.example.com/theDirectory = false
http://www.example.com/theFolder    = false
http://www.example.com/ThefolDeR    = false
http://www.example.com/THEFOLDER    = false
```

---

If you want to select the exact opposite you can do this:

```
^.*[A-Z].*$
```

**[Here](https://regex101.com/r/oF0cS2/3)** is the example.

This returns:

```
http://www.example.com/thefolder    = false
http://www.example.com/theDirectory = true
http://www.example.com/theFolder    = true
http://www.example.com/ThefolDeR    = true
http://www.example.com/THEFOLDER    = true
```

Comment: But that would also match `http://www.example.com/thedirectory` https://regex101.com/r/aN9xL6/1

Comment: Thank you @Patrick2607 but I'm looking for the opposite of that, so the regex returns false on all lowercase.